# C# : .Net : Code working on Console application . Same code is failing when running on WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have an application which is using a module A(.net assembly) and module A  uses module B(.net assembly) and module B uses module C(C++).

Since many applications in the server use this, i have registered the managed modules to registry and installed them in GAC.

Now i am accessing module A(which does all the job) by below code :

**Type moduleAType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ModuleA.Class1");
object class1Object = Activator.CreateInstance(moduleAType);**

The above two lines of Code works fine when running as console application. But the same code throws an error when i deploy it as WCF service and make a request :

**"Could not load the assembly ModuleB or one of its dependencies".**

To try fix the above error in WCF service , i copied all the dlls ModuleA , ModuleB and ModuleC to the bin of my service installation folder and now i get the same above error while browsing the service. I guess some system modules are not being picked up when running as WCF service.

I tried using ProcMon to see where Asp.Net is picking up the dlls from , but i was not able to figure it out. Any suggestions / help would be very helpfull

Note : Both Console App and WCF service run under same user in the same machine.

Comment: have you confirmed `target framework` and `target platform` of your WCF service? it should be compatible with your desired modules. Asking Out or curiosity, what is target framework and platform of your Console App and WCF Service ?

Comment: yes forgot to mention that , i have verified that as well and everything is on Framework 4.5

Comment: And what about platform? AnyCPU/x86/x64?

Comment: The OS is a 32 bit OS and all modules are built on x86

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow made this work for me. Hope it helps others by sharing it.

I did some logging and found that the running directory of my service is c:\windows\system32\inetsrv and in dependency walker i found most of the dlls(system specific) that my ModuleB depends are in c:\windows\system32.

**So i created a shortcut to system32(c:\windows\system32) folder inside inetsrv(c:\windows\system32\inetsrv) and it started working for me.**